# Download RSS - WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download RSS sources and it works perfectly fine when I'm trying the code on my computer. But when I run it on server, I found out that WebClient class do not download the whole page:

The most simple version of code which causes the problem is this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("<rss source>", Path.GetFullPath("File.txt"));
```

I have tried also DownloadString method or XDocument.Load("url") and always the same result - on my computer is everything ok, on server the downloaded XML is not completed. It seems like something on the server stops this downloading - but the size of those files is for example 100 kB, so I think it should not be caused by any size limitation or time expiration.

Comment: Is `DownloadFile` throwing any exceptions?

Comment: No, not any exceptions. It just not download whole XML... the same for DownloadString - no exception but downloaded string is just not complete.

Comment: Try using `WebRequest.Create` to generate a `WebRequest` and then set `WebRequest.Timeout` to be a bigger timeframe and see if that works

Comment: I have just tried it, but still the same issue.

Comment: have you tried exceeding maxRequestLength?  Try adding this in web.config and see <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000"/> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling tcpoffload on the server?

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/disabling-tcp-offloading-in-windows-server-2012